# Differing connotations of prepositions meaning "at" (en, de, a, etc...)

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, interjecciones

Say you have the question "Why  are you at my house?" I'm not sure which preposition is appropriate here, as many of them translate to "at". 
"¿Por qué estás tú en/a/de/... mi casa?"

(On an unrelated note, does anyone know the Spanish equivalent for "What on earth are...")

Comment: Welcome to the site. Next time, if you have two different questions place each one in a different post, please. If someone wanted to search the site to see if it already addresses a proper translation for _"What on earth are..."_ they are less likely to find it under a question about the connotations of preposition "at" than in a question titled "What is a suitable translations for XXX?"

Comment: I agree with Diego, if you can ask the other question independently and edit this question correspondingly it would be of great help to the community.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will move the unrelated note to a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "en" when using "at" as inside a building.

> ¿Por qué estás en mi casa?

(the subject "tu" (you) is hidden in this phrase as it can be understood from context).

The preposition "a" implies direction,

> me voy a casa -> I'm going home

The preposition "de" implies relation or posession.

> salgo de casa -> I'm leaving home
>
> la casa de mi padre -> my father's home
>
> el gobierno de Inglaterra -> England's government

Also, the Spanish equivalent of "What on earth are..." would be

> "¿Qué diablos son..."

(wich roughly translates as "Which kind of devils are..." :D)

Comment: Makes sense. If someone were "at" my house but not technically inside yet, would "en" still be appropriate? (i.e. at the door.)

Comment: yes, you can use it, it is correct.
Or use "cerca" (near) to specify not being inside yet. "Estoy cerca de casa"

Comment: Thanks! I should have remembered cerca, since it's similar to the root circa.